# ffmpeg - Permission denied when running binary, even as root

Tags: ffmpeg

I've compiled ffmpeg for Android with the NDK and transferred the compiled binary to /data/local, but when I try to execute the binary, even as su, the terminal returns 'Permission denied.'

The configure script I use for ffmpeg is:

`NDK=/home/adam/ndk/android-ndk-r9c
PLATFORM=$NDK/platforms/android-19/arch-arm
PREBUILT=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64`

./configure --target-os=linux --arch=arm --enable-cross-compile --cross-prefix=$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --sysroot=$PLATFORM --enable-pic --enable-runtime-cpudetect

`ls -l ffmpeg` outputs:
`-rw-rw-rw- root      root 10338136 2013-12-30 15:54 ffmpeg`

Comment: Hmm... Are you sure that the binary has executable permissions (even for root)? Could you [edit] your question to include the current permissions for the compiled binary? An `ls -l` output for the file will probably do the trick.

Comment: @dotVezz Added 'ls -l ffmpeg' output

Comment: There's your problem. Try `chmod +x ffmpeg` and see if that fixes it. (You may need to run that as root)

Comment: @dotVezz 'chmox +x ffmpeg' returns 'Bad mode'

Comment: Still returned 'Bad mode'. Manually setting permissions in ES File Explorer fixed the issue and the binary executed successfully.

Comment: Great! I've posted an answer which details the steps we've taken. Feel free to upvote and/or mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your file permissions, it looks like a simple permissions problem. The file does not have execution permissions for any users.

You can use many different options to set permissions:

- `chmod` should work on most cases.
- You can also use many file managers to set file permissions individually. The option you wound up using, ES File Explorer, is an excellent example of such.

You should also read up on [Unix Permissions](http://www.dartmouth.edu/~rc/help/faq/permissions.html) if you're not already familiar with the subject. It'll be a great help in the future.